# Jetson Orin NX with ArduCam AR0234

Tags: hardware, nvidia-jetson

I'm working on robotic project. I bought following hardware : Ark Jetson PAB carrier, Orin NX 16 GB and ArduCam AR0234 with MIPI interface. How can I enable this camera with this hardware ?

I was trying to build custom device tree for this jetson carrier that will support AR0234 sensor, but cannot find enough resources to do it. AR0234 should be plug&play, because of jetvariety ArduCam support, drivers are installed correctly but still nothing on /dev/video* .
Don't know what should i even read for enabling this hardware configuration

Comment: If your camera vendor has claimed it to work with Orin NX, then it should be able to provide a driver and DT for Jetson dev kit. From this you would have to adjust DT for your carrier board, and carrier vendor should provide a SDK with custom DT or patch from standard devkits.